# How can I define ImageMagick path in my cshrc

Tags: linux

How can I define ImageMagick path in my `cshrc`?, I tried:

```
setenv PATH /opt/local/bin/convert/:$PATH
```

but it does not work.

Comment: I do not know cshrc, but in bash, one would add this line to your .profile or put it into your script:  export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"

Comment: `csh` set env https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/tcsh-csh-c_shell-set-variable-command/

Comment: in bash     'export PATH=/opt/local/bin/:$PATH'  work, but I want to define it in .cshrc